# Angular custom directive for input validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I,m trying to create simple custom directive in angularJS 
which validates if user types in an an integer or not.

If the user enters an integer then an error message should appear in the
bottom that **"integers are not allowed"**.

Any idea how can i achieve this...?
(A fiddle would be awesome)

and also...

Is this possible to do **WITHOUT** using $scope.$watch ?

Is this a professional and effective way to check for client side input
validation ? (does this approach compromises performance of the application) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-pattern` to validate if it is a valid number or not. Other way is as you asked , create a custom directive. I am going with `notNumber` name, it can be `isNumber` as well with small change.

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('notNumber', notNumber);

function notNumber() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
        if (value) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('notNumber', Number.isNaN(value));
        }
        return value;
      });
    }
  };
}
```

In HTML,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" not-number />
```

Comment: Nope...the code is not working...i don't see any error if user types an integer...can you please make a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than you might have expected.... use [`ng-pattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" ng-pattern="\\d+" />
```

The demo in docs link above is set to this same pattern as default.

As for doing this...of course, providing user feedback live in form is normal. It doesn't alleviate doing server side validation though which must be done

Comment: Nope...the code is not working...i don't see any error if user types an integer...can you please make a fiddle ?